# Severity: 8192 Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Severity: 8192

Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; CI_Pagination has a deprecated constructor

Filename: libraries/Pagination.php

## Line Number: 27

```
class CI_Pagination {

    var $base_url           = ''; // The page we are linking to
    var $total_rows         = ''; // Total number of items (database results)
    var $per_page           = 10; // Max number of items you want shown per page
    var $num_links          =  2; // Number of "digit" links to show before/after the currently viewed page
    var $cur_page           =  0; // The current page being viewed
    var $first_link         = '&lsaquo; First';
    var $next_link          = '&gt;';
    var $prev_link          = '&lt;';
    var $last_link          = 'Last &rsaquo;';
    var $uri_segment        = 3;
    var $full_tag_open      = '';
    var $full_tag_close     = '';
    var $first_tag_open     = '';
    var $first_tag_close    = '&nbsp;';
    var $last_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
    var $last_tag_close     = '';
    var $cur_tag_open       = '&nbsp;';
    var $cur_tag_close      = '';
    var $next_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
    var $next_tag_close     = '&nbsp;';
    var $prev_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
    var $prev_tag_close     = '';
    var $num_tag_open       = '&nbsp;';
    var $num_tag_close      = '';
    var $page_query_string  = FALSE;
    var $query_string_segment = 'per_page';
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  Your old code is not following what is now considered best practice and if you don't update it it will no longer work in future versions of PHP.  In this case it's because a class constructor should be called __construct() instead of whatever the class name is.

Answer (score 9):

Previously we used to declare class constructor using the class name itself

```
Class A
{

public function a(){
}
}
```

Now you need to change a() to construct, like this

```
public function __construct(){
}
```

And the error will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

It is occur with new version of php ,So if you want to remove this error please use _construct() instead of same class name function.

So here you have to user

```
class CI_Pagination {
 public function  __construct() {
 }
}
```

instead of

```
class CI_Pagination {
 public function CI_Pagination () {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Severity: 8192**

Message: Return type of `CI_Session_files_driver::open($save_path, $name)` should either be compatible with `SessionHandlerInterface::open(string $path, string $name): bool`, or the `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

```
Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 132

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\amd_login\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewClass{
}
function __construct(){
} //is used inplace of a function named NewClass for constructor
```

> change function name having same name as class to __construct and it will work. Faced such problem in google maps api v3

Comment: Can you please improve this explanation and provide some sample source code? Otherwise, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For Codeigniter

First Step:

```
class MyClass{
 function __construct(){
    // copy your old constructor function code here
 }
}
```

Next Step(if first step not working):
 Open application\config\autoload.php and edit

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','browser');
```

to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

remove 'browser'

Answer (score -2):

Loader.php 414 line, I have removed Ampersent.

```
$CI->dbutil =& new $class();
```

to

```
$CI->dbutil = new $class();
```

It works fine in php5.x.

Comment: How is this related to the question which asks for differences in the syntax of constructors?