# Message:Undefined variable: category

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have encountered the following problem in the technical panel I made with Php,

Could you help

Code block:

```
<input type="text" class="span5" name="title" value="<?php echo $category->title; ?>"/>
```

Contorellers block:

```
$viewdata = new stdClass();
$category = $this->db->where("id", $id) -> get ("category")->row();
$this->load->view("category_edit", $viewdata);
```

Comment: Please add your error message, the framework you are using and a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller section as:

```
$data['viewdata'] = new stdClass();
$data['category'] = $this->db->where("id", $id)->get("category")->row();
$this->load->view("category_edit", $data);
```

And in view page as:

```
<?php echo $category['title']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with changing your conroller code with below

```
$category['category'] = $this->db->where("id", $id) -> get ("category")->row();
$this->load->view("category_edit", $category);
```

Comment: Teşekkürler Shubhangee, now compared to a different problem:A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; login has a deprecated constructor

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 3

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320062/severity-8192-message-methods-with-the-same-name-as-their-class-will-not-be-co

Comment: i do not understand what's written there

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You have to assign `$category` in `$viewdata` object like below :*

```
$viewdata = new stdClass();
$category = $this->db->where("id", $id)->get("category")->row();

$viewdata->category = $category;
$this->load->view("category_edit", $viewdata);
```

*Show `category` details in your `view` like this :*

```
<input type="text" class="span5" name="title" value="<?php echo $category->title; ?>"/>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: did u check my answer is it helpful or not?